# Regex for allow negative values and decimal values in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to allow only the four decimal values followed by numbers and can allow negative numbers.

```
$(document).on("keyup", "input[name='measuredqty']", function(){
  if (/\D/g.test(this.value)){
    this.value = this.value.match(/^-\d+\.?\d{0,4}/);   
  }
});
```

Comment: `match()` returns an array. Please take a few minutes to read [ask]. You only explained what you want to happen but not what is actually happening. Also always provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression should do what you want:

```
/^-?\d+(\.\d{0,4})?$/
```

- `^` forces starting at the beginning of the string
- `-?` allows an optional minus
- `\d+` allows one or more digits
- `(\.\d{0,4})?` says the decimal part is optional, with up to 4 digits
- `$` forces finishing at the end of the string